# Accessing attribute in another class Tkinter - OOP

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am trying to develop my own GUI application with Tkinker and struggling with the following problem:

I cannot figure out hot to get the `EntryDateVaraiable` from `AddPage` class that is a part of Window class using a function from another class Database that is responsible for working with db.

I've already tried with almost any combination of `app.EntryDateVaraible`, `app.container.EntryDateVaraible`, `app.Frame.EntryDateVaraible`...

and always receives errors like:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1544, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/noxiss/Programming/PythonProgramms/GitHub/Budget_GUI/tk_test.py", line 254, in <lambda>
    AddButton = Button(self,text='Add', command=lambda: DB.Add())
  File "/home/noxiss/Programming/PythonProgramms/GitHub/Budget_GUI/tk_test.py", line 28, in Add
    (str(app.container.AddPage.EntryDateVariable.get()), str(Type.get()), str(Category.get()), str(EntryAmount.get()), str(Payment.get())))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1906, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: container
```

Code:

```
class Database:

    db = sql.connect('Budget.db')
    c = db.cursor()

    def CreateTable(self):

        self.c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dane(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Date DATE,
         Type TEXT, Category TEXT, Amount REAL, Payment TEXT)''')

    def Commit(self):

        self.db.commit()

    def Add(self):


        self.c.execute('INSERT INTO dane(Date, Type, Category, Amount, Payment) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',
            (str(app.EntryDateVariable.get()), str(Type.get()), str(Category.get()), str(EntryAmount.get()), str(Payment.get())))

class Window(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        #creates container for all pages
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = "True")

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        menubar = MenuBar(container)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label='save settings',)
        self.config(menu=menubar)



        #creates dictionary for list of all pages
        self.frames = {}
        #creates the pages from the dictionary
        for F in (StartPage, MainPage, AddPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
class AddPage(Frame):


    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
            Frame .__init__(self,parent)

            EntryDateVariable = StringVar()
            EntryDateVariable .set(DateFunctions.CurrentDate)       

            EntryDate = Entry(self,textvariable=EntryDateVariable)
            EntryDate.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Comment: You haven't specified what is `app` in the context of `DataBase`, why do you expect `app.containter` and such will work?

Comment: Assuming `app` is something you instantiate during `main()` like `app=Window()`, this is not proper OOP approach as your `DataBase` class relies on something that was created outside of the object itself.  In most cases the object should be self contained, and if there are external references outside the class it should be objects that are passed in, not implicitly expected to already exist within your global scope.

Comment: @Idlehands so you suggest to create another main class that will contain the rest of which the application will be made and then I should be able to reference to appropriate attribute in other sub-class?

Comment: As @stovfl mentioned, the classes should be independent.  You just need to figure out the relationship between the classes and how to pass the required information between them without them relying on specific objects.  E.g. in your `.Add()` method, instead of reading a bunch of `str` directly from the `app` object created in main (which `DataBase` *shouldn't* know by itself), pass in the `str` objects themselves as arguments like `def Add(self, entry_var, type_var, ...)` and call it with `DB.Add(str(app.container...), ...)` where you have access to `app` directly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Accessing attribute in another class Tkinter

Don't go this way, let the `class Database` **independent** from the GUI.
Pass the data as `<data sequence>` to `DB.Add(...` instead.

1. Change `def Add(...` to

   ```
   def Add(self, data_seq):
       self.c.execute('INSERT INTO dane(Date, ...) VALUES(?, ...)', data_seq)
   ```
2. Create a instance variable of `class Database` in `class Window` **==** `controller`

   ```
   class Window(Tk):
       def __init__(self):
           ...
           self.db = Database()
   ```
3. Make `EntryDateVariable` a instance variable of `class AddPage`

   ```
   self.EntryDateVariable = StringVar()
   ```
4. Add the methode `def insert_data(self)` to `class AddPage`

   ```
   def insert_data(self):
       data_seq = [self.EntryDateVariable.get(), ...]
       self.controller.db.Add(data_seq)
   ```